# Where do I insert RAM into Elitebook 8540p?

Tags: memory, hp-elitebook, memorystick

I don't see a place that this will fit... Do I have the wrong type? The RAM stick should be a Hp 398708-061, which I believe works for the HP Elitebook 8540p... Am I wrong about this?

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Missing-RAM-slot-in-EliteBook-8540p/td-p/1800127 but you do have the wrong type. According to Google yours is a DDR2 module.

Answer (score 1):

HP 398708-061 is 4GB DDR2 667MHz Fully Buffered Desktop memory not compatible with the HP EliteBook 8540p

For instructions on how to install, check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1odG0I9tO5A

HP Support guide: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c02483867

For compatible RAM spec: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackardEliteBook8540pNotebook.html

So yes, you have the wrong type that cannot fit in on a laptop.